# “Cannot connect to the configuration database” after changing app pool identity in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, administration, central-administration, iis

The main web application on port 80 was running on `sysadmin` account in application. I changed identity to `Domain user` account. Added that user to `config` and `admin` databases as `db owner` and `securityadmin`.

From that onward website is displaying

> Cannot connect to the configuration database.

I added `domain user` into farm admin group also. Still did not worked.

I changed back to `sysadmin` account and working fine. But I don't want use sysadmin account.

Comment: How you change the app pool account, from sharepoint central admin or manaully on all server?e

Answer (score 1):

Here are the best practice to change the app Pool account.

- First add new account into the Managed Account( security > configure managed Accounts)
- Make sure new account Have DBO rights on the Config DB & Content Databasea.
- from Central Admin > security > Configure Service Account...select the App pool and from next drop down select the account. Click OK.
- Now Perform IIS reset on all servers in farm.

http://nikpatel.net/2012/01/25/best-practices-to-change-app-pool-account-for-sharepoint-web-applcation/